# No Area51 on iPad app?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, ios-app

I have some suggesting questions on Area51. When I get a notification in that, the app will switch to Safari. It's inconvenience for me, since I have to log in and don't feel so native. Why does the iPad app not support Area51?

Comment: @Scimonster nope. Each app got its own team, and it's quite possible to have same thing work in one and not the other. That said, there is a real dupe. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard But here, the API is the culprit in both cases.

Comment: @Scimonster true, but even when the API will support it, each app would have to change its code. Different teams, different time schedules. Better have it separated.