# Expatriates SE main site does not show in site list, but Expatriates Meta does

Tags: bug, ios-app

In the iOS app, I tap for the site list and change the filter to "all sites" (as opposed to the options "Main sites" or "Meta sites").
When doing this, Expatriates Meta appears in the list, but the Expatriates main site does not.

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Cellular)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: What do you mean with "Area 51 site"? That the site is in beta?

Comment: I see the main site and meta

Comment: In the IOS app?  I don't.  The list is sorted alphabetically and Expatriates Meta is neither followed nor preceded by Expatriates.  Nor does Area 51 appear near the beginning of the list.

Comment: A down vote for reporting a bug?  "No, it's a feature!"

Comment: The bug report is confusing and unclear. e.g. what does Area 51 has to do with this?

Comment: Only for Expatriates? With the Android app, I can select if I want to see "Main sites" or "Meta sites". If I choose "Main sites", I see the main site for Expatriates SE.

Comment: IOS has "All"/"Main"/"Meta". All shows Expatriates Meta but not Expatriates.  Main shows neither.  Didn't try Meta but I would expect it to not show Expatriates.

Comment: Expats shows fine for me in any view. Area51 isn't there but that isn't a bug (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242440/307988))

Comment: And you still didn't explain what Area 51 got with any of this, @WGroleau.

Comment: I've got the option "All" on the Android app as well. I could not reproduce this on Android (app version 1.0.89). It shows both Expatriates main and Expatriates Meta.

Comment: I understand the bug report now, and have edited the post accordingly. It has nothing to do with Area 51, maybe OP was led to believe this because the site is in beta. Either way it's a valid bug report that the SO devs will want to look at.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: S.L.Barth figured it out.  When I couldn't find it, I hypothesized that it might be because it was Beta, i.e. Area 51 (which also does not show).  But when I was able to get its Meta without Expatriates itself, that hypotheses no longer made sense.