# Expatriates doesn't appear in the list of sites on the iOS app (operator error)

Tags: bug, ios-app, ipad

The iOS app has an icon that gets me a list of SE sites. I have scrolled slowly through the entire list on my iPad, and Expatriates is not there:

[image]

With Patrick's suggestion, I typed "expat" into the search box and they appeared, but they do not appear otherwise.

So, it seems to be a bug, but it is not, as explained in the accepted answer (and in the edited title).

Version 1.6.6.2

Comment: Beta sites are in the list (there are 6 on my list before I even scroll)...

Comment: As for Area 51... [Area 51 on iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257277/307988)

Comment: Expatriates is not on the list for me.  But in response to Patrick's answer, I used then search box and they did appear.  So I will edit my question.

Comment: Isn't this the same as [your previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290761/307988)?

Comment: Wow, I forgot I had written that.  But it's changed.  Now I get neither in the list when I select "all sites"

Comment: AFAIK, you don't see sites in there which you have 'pinned' in your 'Your Communities' list. Could you check if that is the case?

Comment: I didn't know there was any way to "pin" them.  I think that list just defaults to the five sites I use most.  Which I am embarrassed to say includes Expat and it indeed does appear on that sidebar!    Checked the full list for my other top five and @Glorfindel has indeed explained it.  So, not a bug.  You might make that an answer that can be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sites you've selected in your 'Pinned Sites / Your Communities' list (the same sites which appear on top of the list of sites under the [stackexchange-button](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-button) on the main site) **don't appear** when viewing the 'All Sites' screen in the iOS app.

FWIW, they *do* appear in the Android app.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite hard for the team to allow Area 51 in the app. Refer to [Will Area 51 be supported in the app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194896/245360) about that.

Concerning Expatriates and other beta sites: they are available in the app. If I search for Expatriates from the *All Sites* menu option, you will see the site among other beta sites:

> [image: Expatriates]

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried this on iPad (I wouldn't usually - I far prefer using a normal web interface) and as soon as I select the All Sites option (my fault is Main Sites) Expats is on the list.

You don't need to search for it, just scroll down to the "E"s...

Are you sure you are using the correct options in the app?

Comment: I repeat: if it shows different things to different people, it's a bug.  If there are options that can be changed, they are well hidden. What's the use of telling me to scroll to the Es when I said I scrolled through all the letters and posted an image to prove it?

Comment: The difference between "Main" and "All" is that "All" includes Meta.  When I change it to "All," Expatriates _Meta_ appears but Expatriates (Main) does not.